# How to fix iOS crash log [UITraitCollection _initWithBuiltinTraitStorage:tintColor:clientDefinedTraits:environmentWrapper:]

Tags: ios, crash

This is my crash log:

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3c43eb4 objc_retain_x19 + 8
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc47a38 -[UITraitCollection _initWithBuiltinTraitStorage:tintColor:clientDefinedTraits:environmentWrapper:] + 208 (UITraitCollection.m:709)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc74b28 +[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:] + 580 (UITraitCollection.m:1369)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc722d8 -[UIImageView _resolvedImageFromImage:forTrait:] + 208 (UIImageView.m:2752)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc71ef0 -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:previouslyDisplayedImage:] + 324 (UIImageView.m:2802)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc36cc8 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 408 (UIImageView.m:1106)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2060320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2061eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b20706a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2640)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b20702f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7954)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac31d18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac13650 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992 (CFRunLoop.c:3147)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac184dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001e5e8435c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001acfa437c -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3773)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001acfa3fe0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5363)
16  MyApp                           0x00000001004d55e4 main + 72 (main.m:47)
17  dyld                            0x00000001ca0acdec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a3c43eb4 objc_retain_x19 + 8
1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc47a38 -[UITraitCollection _initWithBuiltinTraitStorage:tintColor:clientDefinedTraits:environmentWrapper:] + 208 (UITraitCollection.m:709)
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc74b28 +[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:] + 580 (UITraitCollection.m:1369)
3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc722d8 -[UIImageView _resolvedImageFromImage:forTrait:] + 208 (UIImageView.m:2752)
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc71ef0 -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:previouslyDisplayedImage:] + 324 (UIImageView.m:2802)
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001acc36cc8 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 408 (UIImageView.m:1106)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2060320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b2061eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b20706a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2640)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001b20702f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7954)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac31d18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1780)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac13650 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992 (CFRunLoop.c:3147)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aac184dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001e5e8435c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001acfa437c -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3773)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001acfa3fe0 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5363)
16  MyApp                           0x00000001004d55e4 main + 72 (main.m:47)
17  dyld                            0x00000001ca0acdec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)
```

I can't reproduce this crash during running the program, the log is shared from testflight user.I don't even know in which scenario this problem occurs.